# How to get row data when clicked to populate a modal or form on angular 8

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I return rows of data in a Wizard and have an edit button on each row but would like to be able to open a modal  that is populated with the 
data of the row  that is clicked. I am stuck on the onSelect click event in order to select the row. I understand the theory that is 
get the primary key of the row selected then use that to get the data to  populate  the  modal form to be edited but don't know how to achieve it syntactically

PersonListing.Component.html

```
         <ng-container matColumnDef="FirstName">
           <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> First 
           Name </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.name}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="LastName">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Last 
            Name </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.LastName}} </mat- 
            cell>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions</mat-header- 
             cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                   <span><a role="button" class="link-edit" 
            (click)="onSelect(row)">Edit</a></span>
                </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
```

PersonListing.ts

```
    onSelect():void{
      <!--what to put in here  to prepopulate modal form with row clicked-->
     }
```

Model

```
   export class Person {
        id: number;
        FirstName: string;
        LastName: string;
                        }
```

Comment: You need to get data in "onSelect()"!!do you try this: onSelect(row):void

Comment: Yes I did. Select(row):void does nothing when you click even when inspecting via the developer tool.

Comment: you should add `row` as `parameter` to `onSelect` method.like :
`onSelect(row):void{
      console.log(row)
     }`